# How about a StackOverflow simple Chrome App Launcher?

Tags: feature-request, google-chrome

I've looked on the **Chrome Web Store** for a simple application that points to StackOverflow ou or StackExchange website, kind of a launcher but could not find it.

[image: -1 no freehand circles]

Is there an app for this job?

Comment: Have you looked on StackApps.com? If there is anything it'll be there.

Comment: How exactly is that better than a bookmark?

Comment: it is more practical ... I would love to add a picture to illustrate that but sorry I don't have that privilege.

Comment: You can put the picture elsewhere (e.g. http://imgur.com) put link and someone with high rep will edit it into the post.

Comment: hope someone will edit it

Comment: Well, hell. They removed it. There used to be one, it still works for me.

Comment: When I open a new tab, the cursor is at the omnibox, so all I have to do is type "s" and it automatically fills in `stackoverflow.com`. I don't see much use for this; I would probably type the whole address (stackoverflow.com) faster than I could find and click on the icon anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They removed it. There used to be one, it still works for me.

[image: Like a BAUS]

Comment: that's exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: Unfortunately.....https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kcbmndeppjinjfcpfejngcfkilfagklc

Comment: how about a one for **StackExchange Network** ?

Comment: hey @mikeTheLiar can you edit my post and add my picture to it please ?